# text/csv file download turning to text/plain when hundred rows

Tags: java, spring, csv, download, plaintext

I have used the code below for a csv file download

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(csv.toString().getBytes());
IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());

response.setContentType("text/csv");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=mycsvfile.csv");
response.flushBuffer();
is.close();
```

It worked fine for tens of records. I was able to download a *.csv file.
But it returns text/plain with no file extension for hundreds of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `response.setHeader()` *after* you've already sent the data to the response stream. If the response stream buffer wasn't big enough to handle all of that data, it would *have* to write the headers out in order to write the content. Frankly I'm surprised that `setHeader` isn't throwing an exception to say that the response body has already been started, but anyway...

Just move the header setting part to before the call to `IOUtils.copy`.

I would also *strongly* recommend specifying a character encoding in the `String.getBytes()` call, and specifying the same encoding in the response header. (I generally use UTF-8.)